# How to set variable timing for each photo when making video from photo array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a photos to video app and I would like to have different timing for each photo.  I have an array of durations and an array of photos (item count matches).
The durations are in miliseconds.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<imageArray.count; i++) {

        BOOL append_ok = NO;

        while (!append_ok)
        {
            if(adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
            {
                buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[imageArray[i] CGImage] andSize:size];
                Float64 seconds = [durations[i] floatValue];
                int32_t preferredTimeScale = 1000;
                CMTime imageDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, preferredTimeScale);
                append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:imageDuration];

                if(buffer)
                    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I am doing something wrong with setting the time for each iteration.  Any help  will be greatly appreciated.

This is the error I am getting

2014-10-10 10:53:13.853 Videofy[1636:497297] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:] invalid parameter not satisfying: ((Boolean)(((presentationTime).flags & (kCMTimeFlags_Valid | kCMTimeFlags_ImpliedValueFlagsMask)) == kCMTimeFlags_Valid))'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x26fcbf87 0x3472ac77 0x25ad935d 0xf09ef 0xef1a3 0x2a47b497 0x2a47b439 0x2a46604d 0x2a47ae69 0x2a43fca7 0x26f92845 0x26f8ff29 0x26f9032b 0x26edddb1 0x26eddbc3 0x2e269051 0x2a4a9a31 0xf3b15 0x34cc6aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Have you got the solution? If yes , how do you handled this exception?

Comment: Got the same exception , Solved it. It's a memory leak issue, I have allocated buffer for images and dint deleted, That's where the leak happened.